# Using the Youtube API, can I see if a video is in a playlist without retrieving the entire playlist and looping through all the videos?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have an array of Youtube videos, and I want to know if they are contained in a particular playlist.  I have this code:

```
  var targetPlaylistId = "some_playlist_id";
  var targetPlaylist = YouTube.Playlists.list("snippet", {id: targetPlaylistId});
  var targetPlaylistTitle = targetPlaylist.items[0].snippet.title

  var targetVideos = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list("snippet", {playlistId: targetPlaylistId, maxResults: 50});

  for (var i = 0; i < sourceVideos.length; i++) {
    var sourceVideoId = sourceVideos[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
    var sourceVideoTitle = sourceVideos[i].snippet.title
    var isAlreadyAdded = false;

    for (var j = 0; j < targetVideos.items.length; j++) {
      var targetVideoId = targetVideos.items[j].snippet.resourceId.videoId;

      if (sourceVideoId == targetVideoId) {
        isAlreadyAdded = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!isAlreadyAdded) {
      var resource = {
        snippet: {
          playlistId: targetPlaylistId,
          resourceId: {
            kind: "youtube#video",
            videoId: sourceVideoId
          }
       }
      };
      YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert(resource, "snippet");
      Logger.log("Added video " + sourceVideoTitle + " with ID " + sourceVideoId + " to playlist " + targetPlaylistTitle);
    }
  }
```

This works, but I have to loop over every video in targetPlayList for each one of the sourceVideos, which I don't want to do if targetPlaylist is long.

Is there a way to ask Youtube "is video X already in playlist Y?"